vue and vuetify in shopify app theme extension
I tried Vue and Vuetify CDN to load a v-btn in a .liquid file for shopify app extension but I'm facing an error Blocked script execution in 'https://online-store-web.shopifyapps.com/themes?embedded=...' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.
<div style="width: 80%; display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <v-btn color="primary" @click="onClickAction">Click Me</v-btn>
</div>

<!-- Vuetify 3 CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.0/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Vue 3 and Vuetify 3 JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.31/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.0/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const app = Vue.createApp({
      data() {
        return {};
      },
      methods: {
        onClickAction() {
          console.log("hello");
        }
      }
    });

    app.use(Vuetify);

    app.mount('#app');
  });
</script>

